# Clojure Null Pointer Exception Due to Function Key Mismatch

Tags: clojure

I am working through the beginning of a Clojure for the Brave and True [example](https://github.com/braveclojure/cftbat-code/blob/master/06/the-divine-cheese-code/src/the_divine_cheese_code/visualization/svg.clj):

```
(ns the-divine-cheese-code.visualization.svg
  (:require [clojure.string :as s])
  (:refer-clojure :exclude [min max]))

(defn comparator-over-maps
  [comparison-fn ks]
  (fn [maps]
    (zipmap ks
            (map (fn [k] (apply comparison-fn (map k maps)))
                 ks))))

(def min (comparator-over-maps clojure.core/min [:lat :lng]))
(def max (comparator-over-maps clojure.core/max [:lat :lng]))
```

I am getting a Null Pointer Exception, though, when I try to run the following code in a CIDER REPL:

```
(min [{:a 1 :b 3} {:a 5 :b 0}])
```

I am trying to identify the source of the error within the code.  Any help would certainly be appreciated.

Comment: The keys of the maps don't match

Comment: Thanks @BlackBear!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `comparator-over-maps` uses the vector of keywords that you pass it to look up values in the map. In this case the maps you're passing have keys `:a` and `:b`, but your definition of `min` is requesting the keys `:lat` and `:lng`, which don't exist -- so it receives `nil`, which is the cause of the NPE. If you change one or the other set of keywords to match, then the example should work, e.g.:

```
(min [{:lat 1 :lng 3} {:lat 5 :lng 0}])
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @BlackBear's comment, I reran the code in the CIDER REPL as:

```
(min [{:lat 1 :lng 3} {:lat 5 :lng 0}])
```

and it produced the correct answer:

```
=> {:lat 1, :lng 0}
```

Thanks for your help!